# How to get the sentence number for each words in words table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a a table like:

```
Id     Word
---    ----
1      this
2      is
3      a
4      cat.
5      that
6      is
7      a
8      dog.
9      and
10     so
11     on
```

and need to add a new column for sentence number **base on dot character**:

```
Id     Word     S#
---    ----     --
1      this     1
2      is       1
3      a        1
4      cat.     1
5      that     2
6      is       2
7      a        2
8      dog.     2
9      and      3
10     so       3
11     on       3
```

what is the best solution from the **performance** aspect??

Comment: Do you need to be able to return this as a column when you run a query, or do you actually need to store the sentence number? If you need to store it, can you explain why, and how you're going to keep the entire table up to date any time a single row changes?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need that only when I run the query. then I can store it using _Select into_ and update it using _count of previous dot characters_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select table.id, table.word, count(*) + 1 as serial_number
from table left join
( select id, word from table where word like '%.' ) Z 
on table.id > Z.id
group by table.id, table.word
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because this answer is correct.  The other answer only provides sentence numbers when the word ends in a period.

Comment: My answer provides the same information in the form of an update and matches OP's intention to add a new column to the existing table.

Comment: @shawnt00 the OP replied to my comment and only needs the column as output, not a new column in the table.

Comment: The computed column for serial_number needs to be corrected. For the first sentence in the table there will be no matches in Z. Count(*)  evaluates as a 1 but you really want it start at 0 so the sequence is right. Take a column from the right table instead: count(Z.id) + 1 as serial_number

Comment: Yes, it doesn't surprise me that the union messes up performance. By the way, your queries are probably going to be slower and slower the more rows you add. Did you make sure to change the serial_number expression?

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that sentences are formed by ascending id number. That's a really bad idea.

This query should give you information about the sentence breaks. (Replace "T" with the real table name.)

```
SELECT
    Break1.Id as BreakId,
    COALESCE(MAX(Break2.Id), 0) as PreviousBreakId,
    COALESCE(COUNT(Break2.Id), 0) + 1 as BreakNumber
FROM
    (SELECT Id FROM T WHERE Word LIKE '%.') as Break1,
    (SELECT Id FROM T WHERE Word LIKE '%.') as Break2
WHERE Break2.Id < Break1.Id
GROUP BY Break1.Id
```

Here's how you might use it in an UPDATE.

```
UPDATE T
SET SentenceNum = (
    SELECT B.BreakNumber
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            Break1.Id as BreakId,
            COALESCE(MAX(Break2.Id), 0) as PreviousBreakId,
            COALESCE(COUNT(Break2.Id), 0) + 1 as BreakNumber
        FROM
            (SELECT Id FROM T WHERE Word LIKE '%.') as Break1,
            (SELECT Id FROM T WHERE Word LIKE '%.') as Break2
        WHERE
            Break2.Id < Break1.Id
        GROUP BY Break1.Id
        ) as B
    WHERE T.Id >= B.PreviousBreak AND T.Id < B.BreakId
)
```

I offer the query for educational value but I can't condone the approach based on your information.

**EDIT**

My original version had a problem with the first sentence because basically the logic looks for a preceding sentence break that doesn't exist. @cravoori's solution handles this via a left join. Here's a working version in the same spirit of my own answer which returns the full list of words rather than the breaks. Except for the cross join and the dummy zero row, at heart it's the same.

```
SELECT T.Id, MIN(T.Word) as Word, COUNT(Breaks.Id) as SentenceNumber
FROM T, (SELECT 0 as Id UNION ALL SELECT Id FROM T WHERE Word LIKE '%.') as Breaks
WHERE Breaks.Id < T.Id
GROUP BY T.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this query to get the desired output:

```
DECLARE  @Sentence TABLE(idn int identity,word varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Sentence
VALUES('this'),('is'),('a'),('cat.'),('that'),('is'),('a'),('dog.'),('and'),('so'),('on.'),('I'),('love'),('india.')
--SELECT * FROM @Sentence 
DECLARE @seq int=1
;WITH CTE(idn,word,seq) AS(
SELECT idn,word,CASE WHEN word not like '%.' then @seq END from @Sentence where idn=1
union all
SELECT s.idn,s.word,CASE WHEN s.word like '%.' then c.seq+1  else c.seq END from @Sentence s inner join CTE c on s.idn-1=c.idn
)
,CTE1(idn,word,seq) As
(SELECT idn,word,CASE WHEN word like '%.' then seq-1 else seq end as seq from CTE)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
```